# What is new in django-tastypie 0.10

Tags: django, tastypie

I am looking for release notes what is new in django-tastypie 0.10 but I can not find it. I would like to know what is new before update the package. I am using at the moment django-tastypie 0.9.15. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All the changes can be found [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/compare/v0.9.15...v0.10.0). The breaking changes can be found in the `BACKWARDS-INCOMPATIBLE.txt` file. Unfortunately, `tastypie` doesn't provide a clear changelog.